# Assign value to a variable in a string query at run time

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a string query which i will be getting at run time from the database. In the query i have a variable to which i need to assign the value at run time.

ex:

int id;
String query = select * from table where var1 = id;

Now when i execute this query , it is not taking the id value instead it takes that also as a query string.

In ios we use %@ in place of id and assign the value at run time. Is there any alternative for that in android?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: String query = "select * from table where var1 ="; When you have values in id just do an append String tempQuery = query + id;

Comment: @Triode No, bad! Don't use string manipulation on SQL queries! Use query parameters!

Comment: Yes true I totally agree !!!! May be this would be a more appropriate      

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo The Android database framework allows only string parameters.

Answer (score -1):

simple query, selects everything from db where column id and username match the selection

```
int id = 0;
String name = "somename";
String table = "tablename";
String selection = "column_id = ? AND column_name = ?"
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id), name}

Cursor c = yourDatabase.query(table, null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null, null)
```

Comment: `id` is not a string.

Comment: This does not work if `column_id` does not have a numeric [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity).

Comment: it's nice of you to point that out, but [query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) is limited to Strings and the question was only about generating a query not about database design choices but anyway upvote for your comment because it adds useful information